# Shortcuts do not work on readonly instances of tinymce

Tags: tinymce

I think it might be related to the fact that a not editable iframe is not clickable and therefor cannot get the focus.

Can anyone confirm this?

Is there a workaround of any sort for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what i do if "readonly" is set. This way the iframe does not keep focus and shortcuts are at least working from the parent document.

```
ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
  if (ed.getParam('readonly')) {
    ed.getDoc().addEventListener("click", function(){ $(parent.document.activeElement).blur(); }, true);
  }
});
```